# ナビゲーション・ドロワーのメニューのitemをクリックして画面遷移（Activityを移る）方法

Tags: java, android, android-studio

初めまして、ほぼ初心者です。

ナビゲーション・ドロワーによりメニューを開いて、例えばnav_cameraをクリックして別のActivityに切り替える方法はあるのでしょうか？

buttonのonClickにintentを使ったメソッドを登録して画面遷移する方法はある程度理解しているつもりなのですが、res.menu(？）のレイアウトファイルにbuttonが無いのでどうしたらいいかよくわかりません。

アドバイスお願いします（＞＜）

追記：現状の具体的なコードは以下のようになります。
（ナビゲーション・ドロワーのテンプレートを作成し、その後でMainActivity2を作りました。）

MainActiityは、

```java
package com.wixsite.tobirayt.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity２は

```java
package com.wixsite.tobirayt.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

です。レイアウトなどはまだテンプレートのままなのですが、一部重要だろうと思われる場所を記載すると

res.layout.activity_main_xmlは、

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

となっており、

res.layout.menu.activity_main_drawer.xmlは

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

となっており、まだナビゲーション・ドロワーのテンプレートから何も編集していない状態（Activity2を追加しただけ）です。
今、やりたいことは例えばitemのnav_cameraをクリックするとActiity2の画面へ遷移したいのです。
どこまでコードを書けばよいのかわからなかったので取りあえずこのあたりだけ書きました。もっと書いた方がいいのであれば書きますので、言ってくださると助かります。

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
↑ごめんなさい。上の追記解決したのですが、今私が考えているプログラムには適応できませんでした。正確なプログラムは次の通りです。

二つのActivityがあり、MainActivityとEnglishShortSentenceというActivityです。先に起動するのはMainActivityです。EnglishShortSentenceの方はスワイプ機能とナビゲーションドロワーを同時に実装しています。MainActivityのボタンからはEnglishShortSentenceにいけるのですが、EnglishShortSentenceの方のナビゲーションドロワー内のitemをクリックしてもMainActivityにいけづ困っております。精確に質問しなかったことを後悔しております。ごめんなさい。

MainActivity:

```java
package com.wixsite.tobirayt.memorizationapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        Intent intent =new Intent(this,EnglishShortSentence.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

もう一つのActivityは

EnglishShortSentence:

```java
package com.wixsite.tobirayt.memorizationapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class EnglishShortSentence extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_english_short_sentence);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.english_short_sentence, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            //「ここがうまく行きません。」

            Intent intentt=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentt);

            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void onButtonClick(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // レイアウトファイル名を配列で指定します。
            int[] pages = {R.layout.english_short_sentence_configuration,
                    R.layout.english_short_sentence_problem,
                    R.layout.english_short_sentence_achievement};

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View layout;
            layout = inflater.inflate(pages[position], null);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout);
            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // ページ数を返します。
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }
    }
}
```

です。強引にスワイプ機能とナビゲーション・ドロワーの機能をつけてみました。nav_cameraをクリックするとMainActivityに戻るプログラムを、入れているつもりなのですがこれが機能しません。

manifestsは

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wixsite.tobirayt.memorizationapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EnglishShortSentence"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_english_short_sentence"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

となっております。レイアウトファイルは、結構あるので省略します。必要ならばもちろん、書かせていただきます。

Comment: `if (id == R.id.nav_camera)`のところで、その「intentを使ったメソッドを登録して画面遷移する」の処理を呼ぶ、では解決しないのでしょうか？

Comment: びっくりしました(´д｀)できました^^でもごめんなさい。実は説明の便利上コードを簡略化して説明していました(T^T)、本当はスワイプ機能とナビゲーションドロワーの両方を同時に実装しているプログラムをつくってて、そのプログラムでは今の方法「Intent intent=new Intent(this,Main2Activity)  startActiity(intent)」が使えないのです＞＜。なぜなのでしょうか？今度こそちゃんとしたプログラムを追記しておきます。本当に申し訳ないです。トホホ。。※編集中です（１５分ほどかかります。）。

Comment: 抱えている問題についてですが、どこに原因があるのかを特定していく必要がありそうです。まず何ができていないのでしょうか？`①startActivityによる画面遷移ができていない`のか`② 「ここがうまく行きません。」の処理自体が呼ばれていない`、のか。おそらく後者ではないかと推測しています。

Comment: すみません。忙しくて返信が遅れました。そしてなんとか解決することができました（いろいろといじっていたらできました^^）。原因はactivity.main.xmlにおいてコードを書く順序がおかしかったようです。先にNavigationViewを読み込むのではなく、先にViewPagerを読み込ませるのが正解のようです。xmlのコードは省略して補足に書いていなかったので申し訳ないです。まさかコードのxmlのコードの書く順序が大切だとは知りませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

なんとか解決することができました。

原因は activity.main.xml においてコードを書く順序がおかしかったようです。先に NavigationView を読み込むのではなく、まず ViewPager を読み込ませるのが正解のようです。

まさかコードの xml のコードの書く順序が大切だとは知りませんでした。

---

*この投稿は [@user27664 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42231/%e3%83%8a%e3%83%93%e3%82%b2%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3-%e3%83%89%e3%83%ad%e3%83%af%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a1%e3%83%8b%e3%83%a5%e3%83%bc%e3%81%aeitem%e3%82%92%e3%82%af%e3%83%aa%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e7%94%bb%e9%9d%a2%e9%81%b7%e7%a7%bb-activity%e3%82%92%e7%a7%bb%e3%82%8b-%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95#comment43647_42231) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*